# Confusion of a code snippet in a interview

Tags: python, java, floor-division

I was asked, in an interview, what the below code does.

[image]

```java
class Case {

    static int count1(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int m = n / 2;
        if (2 * m != n) {
            return 1 + count1(m);
        }
        return count1(m);
    }

    static int count0(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        int m = n % 2;
        return count0((n - m) / 2) + 1 - m;
    }

    static boolean equivalent(int n, int m) {
        return ((count1(n) == count1(m)) && (count0(n) == count0(m)));
    }
}
```

First, I have to mention that the job is a data analyst internship and the only language required is Python and I'm a physics student so for me there is a huge difference between "//" and "/".

We first consider the function `count1`. I literally thought it was a trick question because `int(2*m != n)` was a trick question because it might cause a value error (my bad because I've been warned so many times about the difference between "//" and "/" in physics, I completely forgot that in other languages "7" can be used for integer division with a return value for floor division. So I stupidly thought it was a trick question and immediately pointed out that this would possibly give an error message and the `if(2*m !=n)` might be unnecessary.

Now what really confused me is `count0`, the second function. I simply pointed out the program doesn't solve anything, there is no pattern. The interviewer said it's supposed to return 0 or 1, but for it to return 0 or 1 then it's supposed to be `count0((n-m/2+1-m)`, i.e. every term should be inside the parenthesis, right?

This interview took place yesterday evening. Should I write to my interviewer and tell him that even though failing to answer as to what the first function does is my fault but your second function may have a logic error? Of course in a nicer way.

PS: ChatGPT tells me this code is Java so I am adding the tag "java".

As I explained in the above text.

I realise i might have screwed up the first function, however here is the tested result tested using python:

```python
# Implementing count0 function as described in the pseudocode
def count0(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    m = n % 2
    return count0((n - m) // 2) + 1 - m

# We will calculate the values of count0 for n = 0 to 20
results_count0 = {n: count0(n) for n in range(21)}

results_count0
```

results:

```
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 2, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 0, 16: 4, 17: 3, 18: 3, 19: 2, 20: 3}
```

Comment: if this code is Java, it won't compile. that's the only correct answer I see here.

Comment: 1) please check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/85421) - never mind, Abra did it for *you* :-| and even corrected the code :-( 2) have you tested it? 3) is it expected to be Java or Python or pseudo-code?

Comment: Assuming the code would compile `count0((n-m)/2)+1-m` is quite fine. Let's say `n` was 5 - thus the call would be `count0((5-1)/2) + 1 - 1` because `5%2 == 1`. That comes down to `count0(2)` which in turn calls `count0((2-0)/2)+1-0` and since `count0(1)` returns 0 this will yield 1. Hence `count0(5)` would return 1.

Comment: BTW `count1(3)` and `count0(4)` both return `2` (you are correct that "*it's supposed to return 0 or 1*" is not the case, but having `+1-m`  inside the parenthesis will cause infinite recursive calls)

Comment: @user85421  i tested count0 because i know with count1 i screwed up because i forgot how integer division works, in my mind the importance of // and / is too big in python. So for count0 i tested from 0 to 20, i just returned numbers without any pattern but surely not just 0 or 1 3) it is expected to be pseudo code, i had a false understanding of the word i guess.

Comment: @thomas yes but there is no pattern, if we test it from 0 to 20 we will see more than just 0 and 1

Comment: @user85421 i think if we had it inside the parenthesis, we would get to 0 or 1 and the function would return 0 or 1 that way

Comment: if the number is `2`, it will never end without a `StackOverflow` -- `m = 2 % 2 = 0` -- `count0( (2-0)/2 + 1 - 0) = count0( 1 + 1) = count0(2)`

Comment: @user85421 ah i see for numbers that have a modulus of 0 this could happen

Comment: At this level of code complexity, it should be unimportant whether it is or Java/C#/Kotlin or Python. It is some imperative language with spiky parentheses, apparently strong typing (excellent) and apparently classes (note that having classes is unimportant in this particular case). Syntax errors are expected because the people generating these kinds of questions only have a vague idea about proper code & style. The questioner asks you to look for clues and unf*ck the code (hopefully you have a paper sheet & pen or maybe even an IDE to help you).

Comment: As data analyst you should be ready to get hit with R and maybe even Julia and definitely various ETL and graphing tools, so restricting onself to Python (which is not a great language at all IMHO, but famous for being famous) is overly restrictive. Write to your interviewer that you have reviewed the question are ready for a second round if he would be kind enough to keep you in the roster.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at some examples you can see the pattern:

| input number | input number in binary | result of `count0()` | result of `count1()` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 111 | 0 | 3 |
| 8 | 1000 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 1010 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: WOW how did you relate this problem to binary representationn?

Comment: @Tomy the name of the methods could have given you a hint - `count0()` counts the 0s and `count1()` counts the 1s.

Comment: @Tomy the name of the methods is one hint, the other: I tested for numbers from 0 to 16 and the results of the `count0()` method for the numbers 2 (1), 4 (2), 8 (3) and 16 (4) made me print out the numbers in binary representation too.

Comment: @ThomasKläger why didn't you use the shift right operator `>>`  to calculate the value of `shiftedRight` ? This would maybe make the variable obsolete as the meaning would be inheritant by the operator.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer please post your code as a separate answer. It was never my intention to provide "better code" for the OPs question, I just want to give a hint on what the methods do.

Comment: @cyberbrain that was not my code. The added code is irrelevant to my answer and I therefore removed it.

Comment: @ThomasKläger No problemo. My excuses for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For people who like code (code is truth!), here is the betterized version.

This is Java-14+, it can probably be tried out on one of those free online Java consoles if you don't have the tools locally.

Also, for those interested in the details as revealed by the [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/):

- `count0()` generates sequence [A023416](https://oeis.org/A023416): *Number of 0's in binary expansion of n.*
- `count1()` generates sequence [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120): *1's-counting sequence: number of 1's in binary expansion of n (or the binary weight of n)*

```java
package org.example;

public class Sequence {

    static int count1(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int m = n / 2;
        if (2 * m != n) {
            return 1 + count1(m);
        }
        return count1(m);
    }

    static int count1_better(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            int leastSignificantBit = n%2;
            int shiftedRight = n/2; // or use n>>1, whatever
            return leastSignificantBit + count1_better(shiftedRight);
        }
    }

    static int count0(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        int m = n % 2;
        return count0((n - m) / 2) + 1 - m;
    }

    static int count0_better(int n) {
        return switch (n) {
            case 0 -> 1;
            case 1 -> 0;
            default -> {
                int leastSignificantBit = n%2;
                int leastSignificantBitInverted = (1 - leastSignificantBit);
                // the original (n - m) / 2 is really for fractionals
                int shiftedRight = n/2; // or use n>>1, whatever
                yield leastSignificantBitInverted + count0_better(shiftedRight);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        final int limit = 10000;
        for (int i=0;i<limit;i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s: zeros: %3d, ones: %3d\n",
                Integer.toBinaryString(i),
                count0_better(i),
                count1_better(i)
            );
            if (count1(i) != count1_better(i)) {
                throw new Exception("count1() and count1_better() differ at " + i);
            }
            if (count0(i) != count0_better(i)) {
                throw new Exception("count0() and count0_better() differ at " + i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And so:

```text
         0: zeros:   1, ones:   0
         1: zeros:   0, ones:   1
        10: zeros:   1, ones:   1
        11: zeros:   0, ones:   2
       100: zeros:   2, ones:   1
       101: zeros:   1, ones:   2
       110: zeros:   1, ones:   2
       111: zeros:   0, ones:   3
      1000: zeros:   3, ones:   1
      1001: zeros:   2, ones:   2
...
```

Comment: An additional exercise would be to get rid of the recursive calls (which are not even "tail calls" and so cannot be optimized away, even if Java did that, which it does not). Certainly it should be easy to find a version that uses a `while` loop instead ...

Answer (score 0):

In case the sourcecode would be correct (so relates to the text in your question and not the foto of the piece of paper):

`Case.count1(n)` calculates the number of one-bits in the two's complement binary representation of `n`. This is equal to `Integer.bitCount(n)`.

`Case.count0(n)` calculates the number of significant (!) zero bits in the two's complement binary representation of `n`. With significant I mean only zeros are counted that are on positions lower than the most significant one bit.
This could also be calculated with `Integer.bitCount((Integer.highestOneBit(n)<<1)-1-n)`.

> The interviewer said it's supposed to return 0 or 1

These are not the only valid results of `count0`, just for an input of 0, the result is 1 and has to be handled separately, because input 0 doesn't contain any set bits, but still has 1 significant unset (zero) bit, and that is the least significant bit.

`Case.equivalent(m, n)` checks, if the number of one-bits and the number of zero-bits of the two given integers `m` and `n` are the same, so `Case.equivalent(1, 2)` would return `true`.

And relating to `/` vs. `//`: in Java, `/` can be used as division operator for integer and floating point numbers, while `//` marks the start of a line-comment, so that's no operator at all.

Comment: Correction: The special case of handling '1' for `count0()` actually *is* necessary. Using the general case for 1 yields 1, which is incorrect: `count0((n - n%2) / 2) + 1 - n%2` = `count0((1 - 1) / 2) + 1 - 1` = `count0(0)` = `1`

Comment: @DavidTonhofer you're right, thanks to point it out. Don't know what weird steps my brain was taking in the first place ;-)

Comment: Such problems happen regulary, I had to think it through thrice myself.  That's why we have "unit tests" after all.